# How to make a post to wordpress using the api?

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

How can I remotely make a post to a user's blog after he/she gives me his login info using the wordpress api? What method do i need to use, what paremeters should it have, etc? Sample code will be great.

I'd prefer to use the XML-RPC api but others will also be acceptable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yeah you can use `metaWeblog.newPost` or `blogger.newPost`, an example of the first:

http://www.wprecipes.com/post-on-your-wordpress-blog-using-php

uses curl and xmlrpc_encode_request

an example of the second:

http://www.nickycakes.com/post-to-wordpress-remotely-with-xmlrpc-in-php/

yeah and @Francis is correct

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) plugin. Create a post using:

```
http://www.example.com/api/create_post/?nonce=123456789&title=My%20Post&status=publish
```